# Excel removing Pivot Cache unexpectedly

Tags: excel, connection, pivot-table

I'm working with pivot tables in Excel 2007. I'm retrieving the data from a SQL Server database. In the PivotTable Options dialog box, under the Data tab, the 'Save source data with file' option is checked. However, after I delete the connection to the data source, the Pivot table becomes unworkable and if I try to make any selection I get a message box stating that 'The connection for this PivotTable has been deleted.' Is this an Excel bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you delete a connection, Excel also deletes pivot caches based on it. I think it's just how Microsoft decided to design it (probably not the best decision, but it is what it is). As a workaround, import data to a table first, and then base your pivot table on that table, not on a connection directly. Alternatively, just don't delete the connection. What are the reasons you need to delete it?

Comment: Thanks RADO, that's what I needed to know (bizarre idea from MS). The workbook is intended for distribution to a wider public and the data source (SQL Server) won't be available to refresh any data. However, the workaround that you suggest perfectly solves my problem.